# Importing a key for ECDH key derivation in subtle crypto

Tags: javascript, ecdh, subtlecrypto

```js
      let randKey = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(64));
      let importedKey = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey("raw", randKey,
        {
          name: "ECDH",
          namedCurve: "P-256",
        },
        false,
        ["deriveKey"]
      );
```

Yet this fails with the error: `Uncaught DOMException: Cannot create a key using the specified key usages.`

How do I import a key to be used in key derivation?

I am basing my code off this snippet from the subtle crypto docs, which works perfectly:

```js
      let bobsKeyPair = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
        {
          name: "ECDH",
          namedCurve: "P-256",
        },
        false,
        ["deriveKey"],
      );
```

But I want to do this with a key that has already been generated.

I found another stackoverflow question that said to use `[]` in the usages section, but all that did was change the error to just be `Uncaught Error`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your raw P-256 key has 64 bytes, I assume that you want to import a public ECDH key (although you don't mention this explicitly).
For public ECDH keys, an empty list must be used for the key usages. The key usage `deriveKey` is only permitted for private keys.
In addition, the raw public key must be passed in compressed or uncompressed format and it must of course be a valid key for the curve in question (not an arbitrary byte sequence).

In the following code, first a valid raw public key in uncompressed format is generated. To do this, a P-256 key pair is generated, whose public key is then exported in raw, uncompressed format. This is then used to demonstrate how such a key can be imported:

```js
(async () => {

// create key pair
let keyPair = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
    { name: "ECDH", namedCurve: "P-256" },
    true,
    ["deriveKey"],
);
console.log("keyPair:", keyPair)     

// export raw public key (uncompressed format)
let publicKey = await window.crypto.subtle.exportKey("raw", keyPair.publicKey)
console.log("publicKey:", ab2hex(publicKey))

// import raw public key (uncompressed format)
let importedPublicKey = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "raw", 
    publicKey,                               // valid raw public key in uncompressed format
    { name: "ECDH", namedCurve: "P-256" },
    false,                          
    []                                       // empty list
); 
console.log("importedPublicKey:", importedPublicKey)
  
function ab2hex(ab) { 
    return Array.prototype.map.call(new Uint8Array(ab), x => ('00' + x.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');
}

})();
```

---

For completeness: In addition to the raw (uncompressed or compressed) format, public ECDH keys can also be imported in X.509/SPKI format (DER encoded), or in JWK format.
Private ECDH keys cannot be imported in raw format, but only in PKCS#8 format (DER encoded), or in JWK format. The PKCS#8 format for private keys has already been pointed out in the other answer. Permitted key usages are `deriveKey` or `deriveBits`.
Note: Keys in PKCS#8 format or X.509/SPKI format can be loaded and inspected in an [ASN.1 parser](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQg2wBQuGhwkqJKb6oXNDgkTsyvnvsYHYRY1aoLtA89G5uhRANCAAQ9jYB2UDATdw63zQ3qKNJKZfU2pOhyLxscXnenXQeX9muxvLHxF8DPFtCOLqmXKGaoKNCcNnGGntePGfNsuQA7).

Code sample for the import of a private key:

```js
(async () => {

// create key pair
let keyPair = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
    { name: "ECDH", namedCurve: "P-256" },
    true,
    ["deriveKey"],
);
console.log("keyPair:", keyPair)     

// export private key (PKCS#8 format, DER encoded)
let privateKey = await window.crypto.subtle.exportKey("pkcs8", keyPair.privateKey)
console.log("privateKey:", ab2hex(privateKey))

// import private key (PKCS#8 format, DER encoded)
let importedPrivateKey = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "pkcs8", 
    privateKey,                               // valid private key in PKCS#8 format, DER encoded
    { name: "ECDH", namedCurve: "P-256" },
    false,                          
    ["deriveKey"]                             // deriveKey, deriveBits allowed
); 
console.log("importedPrivateKey:", importedPrivateKey)
  
function ab2hex(ab) { 
    return Array.prototype.map.call(new Uint8Array(ab), x => ('00' + x.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');
}

})();
```

---

**Edit** - regarding your question from the comment:
The direct import of a raw private ECDH key is not supported by WebCrypto as described above. In the case of a raw private key, the key must be converted into a format that is supported by WebCrypto, i.e. PKCS#8 or JWK. Regarding PKCS#8, it is best to use a suitable library. Conversion to a JWK, on the other hand, is quite simple.
The following code provides an example of converting a raw ECDH key into a JWK and then importing it:

```js
(async () => {

// sample key pair: raw private key and raw public uncompressed key
let rawPrivateKey = hex2ab("609bbc01a89db655a4941be426d3ce6b2bc820f1e82b11145722c0d2052ef5e7");
let rawPublicKeyUncompressed = hex2ab("04926ce2b12acc5b653a153a4d5ba25dfe44330061badcb702a3d24631a81055e38a2b0c7363985f24aeb6279ce0cc022b947192a692300de5e91ee07bb5acf3e9");
let x = rawPublicKeyUncompressed.slice(1, 32 + 1); // ignore 0x04 start byte for uncompressed format
let y = rawPublicKeyUncompressed.slice(32 + 1);
let d = rawPrivateKey

// convert to JWK
let privateKey = {
  crv: "P-256",
  d: ab2b64url(d),
  kty: "EC",
  x: ab2b64url(x),
  y: ab2b64url(y)
}
console.log("jwk", privateKey)

// import private key in JWK format
let importedPrivateKey = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "jwk", 
    privateKey,                                         // valid private key in JWK format 
    { name: "ECDH", namedCurve: "P-256" },
    true,                          
    ["deriveKey"]                                       // deriveKey, deriveBits allowed
); 
console.log("importedPrivateKey:", importedPrivateKey)
  
// helper ------------

function hex2ab(hex){
    return new Uint8Array(hex.match(/[\da-f]{2}/gi).map(function (h) {return parseInt(h, 16)}));
}

function ab2b64(arrayBuffer) {
        return window.btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)));
}

function ab2b64url(arrayBuffer) {
        return ab2b64(arrayBuffer).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/=+$/g, '');
}

})();
```

Comment: Yes, I need to both import a public and also a private key. The code you posted for importing a public worked for me. The private key in your example is 276 hex characters, but my private key is only 64 hex chars. How can I convert my 64 char priv key into the 276 char format that you're using?

Comment: @ChrisPriest - For the conversion of a private raw key to PKCS#8 an appropriate library should be used (Webrypto itself as a low level library does not support such conversions). An alternative is the conversion to JWK, which should be possible without a library with a little effort.

Comment: @ChrisPriest - Example with conversion of a raw ECDH key into a JWK with subsequent import added.

Comment: Empty usages made it work for me.