# Importing a "raw" private key into the subtle crypto js library

Tags: javascript, cryptography, pkcs#8, subtlecrypto

I have a private key that is just a simple 32 byte private key that was generated somewhere else entirely outside of javascript. I want to import this private key into javascript using the subtle crypto library.

From my experimentation and research, it seems there is no way to import a raw private key. It has to be in either pkcs8 format, or in jwk format.

First, I tried to convert my 32 byte private key into jwk format. I ran into a dead end when I realized that jwk requires the "x" and "y" parameters, which are basically the public key. I don't have the public key, all I have is the private key. I know you can generate the public key from the private key, but I assume that first requires you to import the private key first, which is what I'm trying to do.

Then I tried to convert it to pkcs8, but that also requires the x and y public points, which, again, I do not have.

Is this even possible? I know other crypto libraries let you import raw private keys, but for some reason subtle crypto doesn't let you?

Comment: No, WebCrypto does not allow you to import raw private EC keys, but only as JWK or in PKCS#8 format. This has already been answered in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77559946/9014097) and you can also read about this in the documentation. Read the section [formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/importKey#format) carefully.

Comment: Regarding the conversion of the raw private EC key to JWK and PKCS#8: WebCrypto only supports JWK and PKCS#8 keys with a public portion. Hence, you need the public key to import the private key with WebCrypto. The public key can be derived from the private key (using modular arithmetic). However, WebCrypto does not support this by exposing public methods. If you do not want to implement this yourself (which is not recommendable), you need a tool (e.g. OpenSSL) or an additional library. Or you can replace WebCrypto with another library that supports the direct import of raw keys.